# How to do recursive codecs in argonaut.io?

Tags: json, scala, recursion, scalaz, argonaut

lets say I have a

```
class FooCodecs[A : CodecJson] { 

  def ListCodec: CodecJson[List[A]] = 
    CodecJson.derived[IList](_.toList)(IList.fromList)
}
```

How can I create a codec which supports an arbitrary nested number of `List` like `List[List[List[A]]`?

I've tried supplying a codec for `List[T[_] : CodecJson]`, but it's quite clear that it misses some important type reference to `A`.

So, how do I make it recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a Codec for List, (and it seems it is provided by the traversableOnce instance) and a codec for A, then any nesting of Lists and A's will work. No explicit recursive definition is needed:

```
import argonaut._
import Argonaut._

val a = List(List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))).asJson
a.toString.decodeOption[List[List[List[Int]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @melps writes, this works as expected. My problem seemed to be that `implicit CodecJson[A]` was not found before any of the provided codecs. I had to move codecs to respective companion objects (or i could have put the Argonaut ones in a lower priority context). I don't know why the codecs in the same contexts wasn't found first.